# How Google Analytics works Cumulative values

Tags: ios, mobile, google-analytics

For example I have a code:

int count = 170;

```
NSMutableDictionary *event =
[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Translator Controller"
                                        action:@"TranslatedForCertainTransaction"
                                         label:@"TestTransaction"
                                         value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count]] build];

[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:event];
[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

If I do 3 requests with the values of count (170) what I will get in Google Analytics reports ?

170 or 510 ?

Answer (score 0):

ACtually, both. If you check Top Event reports under Behavior / Events, you can see columns for Event value, which will contain total, and Avg. value for average.

This is also described [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en) in details.

Comment: Please, can you specify what exact value I will see in reports ?    170 or 510 ? Because there is only one resulting value on this label for this event I can see. So it can be 170, 510 or some different value

Comment: If I understand your example well, you'll push the same event 3 times, each with the value 170. In this case, you'll see the following stats: Event category: Translator controller | Total events: 3 | Event value: 510 | Avg. value: 170

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have expected. But how to make a GAIDictionaryBuilder request to monitor only the latest value I sent ? For example I made 3 request: 170, 200,120.  How to get the only latest value I sent (120) in reports because I don't interested in all previous values ? So it should be not-cumulative and just overwrite the previous one

Comment: Well, at this point, it'd be good to understand a bit more of the context and the purpose of the tracking. First of all, you won't be able to delete or overwrite earlier events in Analytics. If you cannot track in your app, which is the latest event to be pushed into Analytics, you could replace event label with a non-personally identifiable ID and a counter, which could then be used to identify latest event of same series in an Analytics custom report. This will however put an overhead on analyzing results.